# Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>' (Angular)

Tags: angular

tengo un proyecto que estaba armando en el que no logro solucionar un problema, que antes no me aparecía, supongo que por la versión de Angular (14).

El codigo es el siguiente:

```
stateOnline$(): Observable<boolean> {
    return merge<boolean>(
      fromEvent(window, 'offline').pipe(map(() => false)),
      fromEvent(window, 'online').pipe(map(() => true)),
      new Observable((sub: Observer<boolean>) => {
        sub.next(navigator.onLine);
        sub.complete();
      })
    );
  }
```

Y el error es el siguiente:

> Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
> Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.ts(2322)
> Type 'boolean' does not satisfy the constraint 'readonly unknown[]'.ts(2344)

Si alguien me podría guiar sobre como resolverlo, seria muy útil, gracias!

Comment: No soy un experto en angular pero te comentaré lo que creo que está pasando. Mirando tu código, supongo que lo que hace `merge` es combinar los tres observables en uno solo de tipo booleano. Ahora bien, el primer y el segundo observable son de tipo booleano, pero el tercer observable NO es de tipo booleano. De ahí que la combinación de algo booleano con algo que no es booleano de `unknown`. De ahí que te diga `Type 'Observable<unknown>'` (que es lo que te devuelve el merge) no es asignable al tipo que dices que vas a devolver en tu función `'Observable<boolean>'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> De esta forma lo acepta en Angular 14   Lo probé sin conexión muestra
> false con conexión muestra true. importar **merge** desde **rxjs**

```
merge desde --->rxjs

import { fromEvent,    Observable, Observer, pipe, Subscription ,of, Subject,merge} from 'rxjs';

import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
 offlineEvent!: Observable<Event>;
  onlineEvent!: Observable<Event>;
 ngOnInit(): void {
  let y= this.handleAppConnectivityChanges();
y.subscribe(s => {
  console.log(`The conexion value is ${s}`);
})
}
private handleAppConnectivityChanges():Observable<boolean> {
    let u = merge (
   
      fromEvent(window, 'offline').pipe(map(() => false)),
      fromEvent(window, 'online').pipe(map(() => true)),
      new Observable((sub: Observer<boolean>) => {
        sub.next(navigator.onLine);
        sub.complete();
      })
      
    )
     return u 
    
  }
```

> Con la  libreria rxjs/operators como **merger** esta en desuso usar
> **mergeWith**

```
    import { map,mergeWith} from 'rxjs/operators';
      ngOnInit(): void {
    this.handle$().subscribe(estado=>console.log('Estado:',estado))
}
    public handle$():Observable<boolean>{
        let false$= fromEvent(window, 'offline').pipe(map(() => false));
        let true$= fromEvent(window, 'online').pipe(map(() => true));
        let new$=new Observable((sub: Observer<boolean>) => {
          sub.next(navigator.onLine);
          sub.complete();
        });
       return true$
              .pipe(mergeWith(false$,new$))
      }
    }

merge  desde rxjs
    (alias) function merge<A extends readonly unknown[]>
    (...sources_0: ObservableInputTuple<A>): Observable<A[number]> (+3 overloads)
    
    
    mergeWith desde rxjs/operators
    (alias) function mergeWith<T, A extends readonly unknown[]>
    (...otherSources_0: ObservableInputTuple<A>): OperatorFunction<T, T | A[number]>
    import mergeWit
```

> merge desde rxjs/operators al estar definida con:

```
interface UnaryFunction<T, R> {
  (source: T): R;
}
 type ObservableInputTuple<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: ObservableInput<T[K]>;
};
function merge<T, A extends readonly unknown[]>(
  ...sourcesAndConcurrency: [...ObservableInputTuple<A>, number]
): OperatorFunction<T, T | A[number]>;
```

> requiere de una fuente Observable que cuando nos subscribimos a merge
> nos subscribiremos a la fuente y a todos los observables suministrados
> como argumentos

```
const delayedMessage = (message: string, delayedTime: number) => 
  EMPTY.pipe(startWith(message), delay(delayedTime));

  const mergeMessage = 'Merge message ';
  EMPTY.pipe(
  merge(
    delayedMessage(mergeMessage + 1, 1000),
    delayedMessage(mergeMessage + 2, 3000),
    delayedMessage(mergeMessage + 3, 2000),
    delayedMessage(mergeMessage + 4, 1000),
    delayedMessage(mergeMessage + 5, 4000),
    // clear the screen
    delayedMessage('', 6000)
  ))
  .subscribe((message: any) => console.log(message));
```

Tomado como base el ejemplo :
para que se ejecute desde rxjs/operators lo modifico al crear una fuente
y mostrara los mensajes no por el orden en el que se ejecutan si no cuando cada uno se complete lo cual es la caracteristica de merge
Ejemplo Modificado [RxJS 6](https://www.htmlgoodies.com/javascript/executing-rxjs-6-observables-in-order/)